# (java) from JTree to XML

Tags: java, xml, jtree

I want to do exactly what was asked here :
[Convert JTree to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588043/convert-jtree-to-xml)
And the answer he got was nice BUT when I try do use it I got a INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR.

Here is an example of a XML file I have put in a JTree :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<company0>
<staff id="1001">
    <firstname>yong</firstname>
    <lastname>mook kim</lastname>
    <nickname>mkyong</nickname>
    <salary>100000</salary>
    </staff>
    <staff id="2001">
    <firstname>low</firstname>
    <lastname>yin fong</lastname>
    <nickname>fong fong</nickname>
        <salary>200000</salary>
    </staff>
</company0>
```

And I'd like to make a function that returns a string (or directly a XML file) that returns the contents of the JTree.

How could I do that ?

Comment: The code you linked to may fail because it attempts to create an element based on the node without checking if it is valid (for example, an empty string): `Element el = doc.createElement(node.toString());`. It *might* work if your XML document has no spaces between the tags. To use with your file as it is, you would need to create new elements only when `node.toString()` produces a valid token.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for your answer. But does this means it won't be able to handle things such as `<staff id="1001">` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your 'createTree' should probably look like this:

```
private static Element createTree(Document doc, TreeModel model, Object node) {
        Element el = doc.createElement(node.toString());
        for(int i=0;i<model.getChildCount(node);i++){
                DefaultMutableTreeNode child = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)model.getChild(node, i);
        if (child.isLeaf()) {
                    el.setTextContent(child.toString());
         } else {
                    el.appendChild(createTree(doc,model,child));
        }
    }
    return el;
}
```

Because the original `createTree` converts node values to elements as there was a check (in the if condition above) missing